# Не отправляются данные с checkbox на сервер

Tags: html, python, django, bootstrap

Код для формы такой

```
<div class="container">
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0" action='SearchInfo/' method="GET">
   <div class="row" style="margin-left: 33%; margin-top: 10%">
     <div class="col">
       <label for="video" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">
         Video 
         <input style="margin:10px;" type="checkbox" id="video" class="badgebox">
       </label>
       <div style="display: inline-block;">
         <label for="code" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">
           Code 
          <input style="margin:10px;" type="checkbox" id="code" class="badgebox">
         </label>
       </div>
       <div style="display: inline-block;">
         <label for="science" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">
          Science 
           <input style="margin: 10px;" type="checkbox" id="science" class="badgebox">
         </label>
       </div>
       <div style="display: inline-block;">
         <label for="wiki" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:5px;">
           Wiki 
          <input style="margin:10px;" type="checkbox" id="wiki" class="badgebox">
          </label>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row" style="margin-left: 15%;">
     <div class="col">
     <input name='search' style="float:right;margin-top:10%;text-align:center;background:wheat; width:500px" type="text" class="form-control prop" id="input_search" placeholder="Enter search word here...">
     <button style="margin-left:48%;margin-top:10px; " class="btn btn-warning text-center button" id="search_btn" type="submit">Search Article</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Затем на веб-интерфейсе ставлю галочки пишу в поле search данные и ожидаю что на сервер придут данные : с тех галочек на которые я нажал придет "on" и данные ввода в поле search

На сервере смотрю что пришло :

```
print(request.GET)
```

В итоге результат такой

```
<QueryDict: {'search': ['test']}>
```

А данных с checkbox нету. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы забыли добавить атрибут name для галочек

Comment: А атрибут label for наоборот не нужен, если галочка лежит внутри него

Comment: да, спасибо, работает